# can somebody give example of using audio engine of cocos2d javascript port

Tags: javascript, audio, cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d objective c port, we can easily play sound effects by:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharekEngine] playEffect:@"xyz.wav"];
```

What am I supposed to use for javascript port of cocos2d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell cocos2d for Javascript does not have audio functionality. See this thread from last year:

http://cocos2d-javascript.org/2010/Dec/10/site-launched-for-cocos2d-javascript

As stated, you can play sounds this way:

```
var crash = new Audio("crash.mp3");
crash.play();
```

That's it.

Comment: thank you, in addition, this method that you recommend does not work with google chrome, is there any alternative of it?